# How to call java jar from actionscript

Tags: actionscript

I need to call java command line jar file directly from actionscript code, and I need to read the jar's output back, is this possible? and how?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on @inverse answer and few other resources:

```
    var startupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();
```

// Define java process -- insert path to java executable -- in my case:"C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_45/bin/java.exe"
startupInfo.executable = new File("[path to java executable]");

// Setup arguments: 
var args:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
args.push("-jar");

// Here you push your jar path:
args.push("[path to jar]");

// next add any argument you have
args.push("[argument]");
args.push("[argument]");

startupInfo.arguments = args;

var nativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
nativeProcess.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.STANDARD_OUTPUT_DATA, onOutputData); 

nativeProcess.start(startupInfo);

function onOutputData(event:ProgressEvent):void 
{ 
    var stdOut = nativeProcess.standardOutput; 
    var data:String =      stdOut.readUTFBytes(nativeProcess.standardOutput.bytesAvailable); 
    trace("Got: ", data); 
}